# How to scrap all webpage successfully?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I tried to scrap a webpage and I get unrelevant texts instead of html tags whereas request's status code is 200.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://understat.com/league/La_liga"

res = requests.get(url)
content = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")

print(content.prettify())
```

Unrelevant texts:

```
x22,\x22games\x22\x3A\x2226\x22,\x22time\x22\x3A\x222086\x22,\x22goals\x22\x3A\x220\x22,\x22xG\x22\x3A\x220.7800159454345703\x22,\x22assists\x22\x3A\x220\x22,\x22xA\x22\x3A\x220.21609876118600368\x22,\x22shots\x22\x3A\x229\x22,\x22key_passes\x22\x3A\x224\x22,\x22yellow_cards\x22\x3A\x222\x22,\x22red_cards\x22\x3A\x222\x22,\x22position\x22\x3A\x22D\x20S\x22,\x22team_title\x22\x3A\x22Real\x20Betis\x22,\x22npg\x22\x3A\x220\x22,\x22npxG\x22\x3A\x220.7800159454345703\x22,\x22xGChain\x22\x3A\x224.666777674108744\x22,\x22xGBuildup\x22\x3A\x224.53211510553956\x22\x7D,\x7B\x22id\x22\x3A\x222148\x22,\x22player_name\x22\x3A\x22Joaqu\x5Cu00edn\x22,\x22games\x22\x3A\x2217\x22,\x22time\x22\x3A\x22343\x22,\x22goals\x22\x3A\x220\x22,\x22xG\x22\x3A\x221.027239991351962\x22,\x22assists\x22\x3A\x221\x22,\x22xA\x22\x3A\x221.3191349804401398\x22,\x22shots\x22\x3A\x226\x22,\x22key_passes\x22\x3A\x2219\x22,\x22yellow_cards\x22\x3A\x222\x22,\x22red_cards\x22\x3A\x220\x22,\x22position\x22\x3A\x22M\x20S\x22,\x22team_title\x22\x3A\x22Real\x20Betis\x22,\x22npg\x22\x3A\x220\x22,\x22npxG\x22\x3A\x221.027239991351962\x22,\x22xGChain\x22\x3A\x223.506589997559786\x22,\x22xGBuildup\x22\x3A\x222.1130624152719975\x22\x7D,\x7B\x22id\x22\x3A\x222168\x22,\x22player_name\x22\x3A\x22Beb\x5Cu00e9\x22,\x22games\x22\x3A\x224\x22,\x22time\x22\x3A\x2251\x22,\x22goals\x22\x3A\x220\x22,\x22xG\x22\x3A\x220.05082689970731735\x22,\x22assis
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get that text basically because the website uses a JavaScript Object. You have to extract the data from the JS object. Try this:

```
script_tag = content.find("script", text=re.compile("playersData"))

json_data = re.search("playersData\s+=\s+JSON.parse\('([^']+)", script_tag.string).group(1)

json_data = json_data.encode("utf-8").decode("unicode_escape")
players_data = json.loads(json_data)

# Print the extracted data
print(players_data)
```

Answer (score 2):

To decode the data you can use `ast.literal_eval`/`json`:

```py
import re
import json
import requests
from ast import literal_eval

url = "https://understat.com/league/La_liga"

res = requests.get(url)

data = re.search(r"datesData\s*=\s*JSON.parse\(\'(.*)\'\)", res.text)
data = json.loads(literal_eval('"' + data.group(1) + '"'))

# uncomment to print all data
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for result in data:
    print(
        "{:<30} {:<30} {:^3}-{:^3}".format(
            result["h"]["title"],
            result["a"]["title"],
            result["goals"]["h"],
            result["goals"]["a"],
        )
    )
```

Prints:

```
Osasuna                        Sevilla                         2 - 1 
Celta Vigo                     Espanyol                        2 - 2 
Real Valladolid                Villarreal                      0 - 3 
Barcelona                      Rayo Vallecano                  0 - 0 
Cadiz                          Real Sociedad                   0 - 1 
Valencia                       Girona                          1 - 0 
Almeria                        Real Madrid                     1 - 2 
Athletic Club                  Mallorca                        0 - 0 
Getafe                         Atletico Madrid                 0 - 3 
Real Betis                     Elche                           3 - 0 

...
```